# Pattern matching at multiple levels

Tags: pattern-matching

Pattern matching is my favorite feature. Is it possible to destructure a symbol but still refer to the whole symbol? I mean something like (this won't work of course)

```
prependIfBigEnough[List_[a_,b___],x_]:=Prepend[List,x]/;x>a
```

What I want to avoid is doing some destructuring on the right-hand-side

```
prependIfBigEnough[list_, x_] := Prepend[list, x] /; x > list[[1]]
```

or repairing the destructured symbol on the right-hand-side

```
prependIfBigEnough[List[a_, b___], x_] := Prepend[List[a, b], x] /; x > a
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Does  `prependIfBigEnough[{a_, b___}, x_] := {x, a, b} /; x > a` do what you want?

Comment: `f[list:{a_, b___}, x_] := Prepend[list, x] /; x > a ; f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 5]`

Comment: Thank you @I.M. , that is exactly what I seek.